# php-opencloud openstack download image but unable to save it in a local file

Tags: stream, openstack, php-opencloud

Using php-opencloud, I manage to connect to trigger the download of my images. Large files (20, 30, or 50 GB).

[Following the doc](https://php-openstack-sdk.readthedocs.io/en/latest/services/images/v2/images.html#download-binary-data), with

```
$image = $service->getImage($image_id);
$stream = $image->downloadData();
```

I can see that Psr7 is downloading request body in a temp file `/tmp/php...` but I simply can't figure how to redirect the data to store them in a persistent local file.

Using fopen, fwrite I had problem of memory exhaustion and a

```
$fp = fopen( $local_file, 'w' );
stream_copy_to_stream( $image->downloadData(), $fp );
```

triggers no error but $local_file is still at 0 bytes at the end.

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

I tried during hours and I knew it was dumb as hell :

```
while( !$stream->eof() ) {
  $buffer = $stream->read( 4096 );
  fwrite( $fp, $buffer );
}

fclose( $fp );
```

is working nicely